# How to use Octave/Matlab Inline function in Scilab

Tags: scilab

How to use this Octave/Matlab inline function in Scilab?

```
u = inline('t>=0') where t=0:0.001:1.
y = (u(t-0.2)-u(t-0.3))
```

I tried it in Scilab as

```
deff('[u]=f(t)','u=(t>=0)')
```

But I am getting an error as "invalid index" in determining 'y'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike in Matlab, invoking `(t>=0)` gives you a boolean vector, its entries are True or False. Since you want 1s and 0s, you need `bool2s` to convert from boolean to integers:

```
deff('[u]=f(t)','u=bool2s(t>=0)')
```

After that you can invoke the function like any other:

```
t = 0:0.001:1
y = u(t-0.2)-u(t-0.3)
plot(t,y)
```

[image: plot]

Personally, I never see the need for inline functions in Scilab.  If I were writing the above, I would declare the function normally:

```
function y = u(t)
    y = bool2s(t>=0)
endfunction
```

Unlike Matlab, Scilab allows you to have such functions appear wherever you want them in the script.